# Can I combine resources in a RESTful API?

Tags: rest

My application has "documents", which are essentially just images, and those documents have "regions". The regions simply define the x and y coordinates on a document in order to draw a rectangle and crop the document. A document can have many regions.

Since regions depend wholly on documents, as in they can't exist without a document to be a part of, would my endpoint to create a region look like this?

```
POST /documents/{document_id}/regions
```

or like this?

```
POST /regions
```

In the second case, I'd have to pass in the document ID via JSON parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option. As a general rule, anytime you're interacting with an existent resource by passing an ID in the payload instead of a direct URI, you're doing RPC, not REST.